# How to Import Rollout.io in SWIFT Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, rollout

I am trying to install rollout.io its simply it says put thus code in you ApppDelegate the problem is that it is in Objective-C. So i used a converter to try and change it to Swift but it doesn't work when i try to put the Objective-C import header into my code. Even when i try to convert it the Online converter doesn't even show the "import" part

Ive tried these all ready

Code:

```
import  Rollout
import rollout
import UIRollout
```

all of these fail.

i can get the bottom part in the swift eject but not the top"import ,Rollout/Rollout.h>" part

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

## Note:

The following will allow you to setup Rollout SDK in case your AppDelegate is in Swift.

## Update:

Rollout SDK 1.1.0 has Swift interface for calling the setup, so all the following info is not relevant now.

## The original answer:

### 1. Swift-ObjC Bridging Header

To call `[Rollout setupWithDebug:]` from Swift, you should have Objective-C Bridging Header set and `<Rollout/Rollout.h>` should be imported from it:

1. In the build settings, check if SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER is already set. If yes, go to step 4
2. Create a C header (*File -> New -> File... -> iOS -> Source -> Header File*). Call it somehow, e.g. `ObjC-Bridging-Header`
3. Go to the build settings and set `SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER` to point to the file you've created (`ObjC-Bridging-Header.h`). A relative path is required in the setting if the file is not at the project's root - more details [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27260533/390928)
4. Go to the header and add the import line there:

   `#import <Rollout/Rollout.h>`

### 2. `#if debug`

In order to allow Rollout testing mode (for easy hot-patches testing) it's also required to translate `#ifdef Debug` from ObjC . This can be done by setting `OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS` in build settings like this:

[image]

### 3. Call setup from AppDelegate.swift

Now you can add the following lines to `application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?)`:

```
    #if DEBUG
        Rollout.setupWithKey("<rollout_key>", developmentDevice: true)
    #else
        Rollout.setupWithKey("<rollout_key>", developmentDevice: false)
    #endif
```

Comment: you can now update your answer to the Rollout SDK that supports swift