# No such module in swift but the framework is there

Tags: ios, swift, imageview, cocoapods

I want to expand image after tapping so I used pods to install it but after that it didn't works and I got this Error

> No such module in AKImageViewerViewController.h

```
    import UIKit
    import AKImageViewerViewController.h
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var aKImageViewerViewController: AKImageViewerController = AKImageViewerViewController()
        aKImageViewerViewController.image = UIImage.imageName("lion.png")
        aKImageViewerViewController.imgCancel = UIImage.imageNamed("btn_cancel.png")
        self.view.addSubview(aKImageViewerViewController.view)
        aKImageViewerViewController.centerPictureFromPoint(CGPointMake(0, 0), ofSize: CGSizeMake(30, 30), withCornerRadius: 1.0)
    }
```

header

```
#import "AKImageViewerViewController.h"
```

I did check the build settings and updated it but didn't works
I uploaded the project https://www.dropbox.com/s/cjk38qh8lf58rkg/imageFU.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

try

If the frameworks are placed in your project directory, simply set the framework search path to `$(SRCROOT)` and set it to recursive.

is not in `import AKImageViewerViewController.h`, it is `import AKImageViewerViewController`

Comment: Old error gone but I got new error instead   <unknown>:0: error: bridging header '/Users/**/Desktop/imageFU' does not exist

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26096402/xcode-myprojectname-bridging-header-h-does-not-exist

Comment: @marrioa -- would you need the additional help for your issue