# Error, bridging header test.h does not exist

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode7, objective-c-swift-bridge

So I am going crazy, since I keep on getting the error as described in the title and nothing that I worked.

I will show you what I have tried:

[image]

[image]

[image]

What else can I do?

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode MyProjectName-Bridging-Header.h does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26096402/xcode-myprojectname-bridging-header-h-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 8):

> **Creating Bridging Header File Manually**

First of all delete the **Bridging header file** which Xcode or may be you have created. And Select your project goto > **Build Settings** > Search the keyword. **Swift Compiler - General**. Click on Objective-C Bridging Header , delete that path. Now clean your Project.

> Now select your project > Click on **Window** in the navigation bar .
>   Select **Projects** and delete your **derived** data from there.

Now create a new **file** , select the **Source** and then select the **Header File** and create your Bridging header file . File name must be your **projectname-Bridging-Header.h** and then create it

> Select your project **goto** > **Build Settings** > Search the
>   keyword. **Swift Compiler - General**. Click on Objective-C Bridging
>   Header and now add the path in this Objective-C Bridging Header like
>   **projectname-Bridging-Header.h**

Now import your classes into bridging header file and you can compile it your code easily.

[Your bridging header file looks like this when you are creating your file manually.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDCSi.png)

Comment: I have answered the question since one year ago, At that time Swift compiler is under Code Generation. Now you are checking in the latest Xcode 9. Apple change their feature time to time. I will update it. @Sreejiths
Thanks for your update

Comment: @Sreejiths You can check even in the question also. He has added the screenshot Okay

Answer (score 3):

In your project you don't have bridging-Header.h file, but your project has that path. For this you need to delete that path...

Go to targets file and select  Build Settings, ---->Swift Compiler - General, and delete the bridging-Header.h. Follow below screen shots....[image]

Delete the bridging-Header.h file in Swift Compiler - General

[image]

Now you got like this...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If above solutions doesn't work,  follow this steps:

1. Create bridging header as usually.

[image]

2. in Build Settings add prefix + / + bridging file name.

[image]

This works for me!

Answer (score 0):

remove path at project goto > Build Settings > Search the keyword. Swift Compiler - General -> Objective-C Bridging header worked for me.