# ObjC Header-Only Import in Swift: No Such Module error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I've converted an app project from ObjC to Swift. It uses several ObjC frameworks that are managed with Cocoa Pods.

When I try to build it I get an error:

> No such module 'Foo'

The Foo file is an ObjC header file that has no .m file. It is used to bind several other classes into one import (in ObjC). here's how the Foo.h would look:

```
#import <Foo/FooDefines.h>
#import <Foo/FooToken.h>
#import <Foo/FooAccount.h>
#import <Foo/FooAccountPersistenceInformation.h>
#import <Foo/FooAccountUserInformation.h>
#import <Foo/FooSettings.h>

// Authenticators
#import <Foo/FooAuthenticator.h>
#import <Foo/FooAnonymousAuthenticator.h>
#import <Foo/FooUserPasswordAuthenticator.h>

// UI
#import <Foo/FooViewController.h>
#import <Foo/RLoginDialog.h>
#import <Foo/RLogoutDialog.h>
#import <Foo/RAccountSelectionDialog.h>
#import <Foo/RVerificationDialog.h>
#import <Foo/RBuiltinLogoutActionSheet.h>

// Workflows
#import <Foo/RLoginWorkflow.h>
#import <Foo/RVerificationWorkflow.h>
#import <Foo/RLogoutWorkflow.h>
```

How would I be able to import this successfully in a Swift class to get beyond the compile-time error?

Comment: You should add classes into "Bridging Header"

Comment: add all your Objective-C .h file imports in "$(PROJECT_NAME)-Bridging-Header.h " file. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26096402/xcode-myprojectname-bridging-header-h-does-not-exist?noredirect=1&lq=1 for more info

Comment: @suhit Hmm I've added `#import <Foo/Foo.h>` to the bridging header file but still getting the same error (after clean).

Comment: can you add all the imports inside <Foo/Foo.h> file in Bridging-Header file and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `#import <Foo/Foo.h>` or `#import "Foo.h"`

Comment: Please confirm whether you have used this inside the bridging header and cleaned project each time.

Comment: Confirmed but not working! Side question: Do I need to have use_frameworks! in my pod file for the Swift target? I'm also getting a warning when using `pod install`: [!] The Podfile contains framework targets, for which the Podfile does not contain host targets (targets which embed the framework).
If this project is for doing framework development, you can ignore this message. Otherwise, add a target to the Podfile that embeds these frameworks to make this message go away (e.g. a test target).

Comment: Another oddity: Besides Xcode I'm using AppCode and in AppCode I can CMD-click the non-imported classes in my code and it jumps to them. But the imports aren't found.

Comment: Yup you need to use  "use_frameworks!" in podfile for swift target. Sorry I haven't tried AppCode yet.