# I need to use a swift class in objective-c and cannot setup my Emilos-Swift.h bridging file to resolve any swift classes in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging

Cannot get Xcode to generate the bridging file so it's currently empty and cannot find any guide/docs on what needs to be in the file.  The empty bridging file is being imported in the .m where the class is needed. Swift file using @objcmembers on class definition.

How and what should go into the bridging file.  Have looked for two days trying to make this work with no success.

Is there a way to turn back on the automatic generation of the bridging file in Xcode?
Any docs on the contents of the bridging file?

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26096402/xcode-myprojectname-bridging-header-h-does-not-exist

Comment: Thanks guys.  I turns out that you do not need a bridging header if only needing a class from the swift side.

Comment: @JamesBonner Yep, that's what my answer tells you...

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse the two kinds of header. The "bridging header" is for Swift to see Objective-C code. It isn't relevant here.

The way Objective-C sees Swift code is through the *generated interface header*. You can see its name in your app target build settings:

[image]

So what that tells you is that if you `#import "MomApp2-Swift.h"` in your *.m* file, your Objective-C code will see your code that is exposed from Swift.

If you want to see what is *in* that generated interface header, then after you've done that import, Command-click on the file name.

Answer (score 0):

To use a Swift class on objective-c you need to be sure that your class inherits from `NSObject`, has an `@objc` annotation on class definition and other elements that you want to use need to be marked with `@objc`. `@objcmembers` marks all elements visible from an Objc class located on file that imports the `"project-Swift.h"`

You may not need all class members visible from Objective-c